# How to draw $S^1\times I$

Tags: general-topology

I always thought $P=S^1\times I$, where $S^1$ is the circle and $I=(0,1)$ with the standard topology is the surface of the cylinder, but I was reading a book which says me another thing:

[image]

Even, if the book is right, I didn't understand why $P$ is the open annulus, because the radius inside the annulus is not the same as $S^1$.

So, why $P$ is not the surface of the cylinder? why $P$ is the open annulus? what the author said doesn't convince me.

Thanks

Comment: Topologically, you cannot "see" the radius. So to go from one to the other, just "push" the middle out to make a cylinder.

Comment: When you say you think it's the surface of a cylinder, do you think it includes the discs at each end, or just the tube?

Comment: So what happens if you shrink the top end of the tube a little, then expand the bottom part a little (so it's kind of a cut-off cone), then smash the whole thing flat into the floor?

Comment: @MartianInvader We get the open annulus?

Comment: @MartianInvader So both are $P$?

Comment: The closed cylinder and closed annulus are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 5):

Let $C$ be the cylinder consisting of the set of points in 3-space with cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ such that $r=1$ and $0 \lt z \lt 1$.

Let $A$ be a particular example of an annulus $-$ say, consisting of the set of points in the plane with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ such that $1 \lt r \lt 2$.

The cylinder $C$ is probably what you have in mind when you think of $S^1 \times (0,1)$. But the function which maps $(1,\theta,z) \in C$ to $(z+1,\theta) \in A$ is a homeomorphism. So the topological spaces $C$ and $A$ are both the same as the space $S^1 \times (0,1)$ (where "the same as" means "homeomorphic to").

Comment: Why $(z+1,\theta)$?

Comment: @user42912 The goal was to show that $C$ and $A$ are homeomorphic; the direct way to do this is to given an example of a continuous function $f:C \rightarrow A$ whose inverse is also a continuous function. The function $f(1,\theta,z)=(z+1,\theta)$ (using cylindrical and polar coordinates, respectively), is just an example; I chose "$z+1$" since $C$ has $0 \lt z \lt 1$ while $A$ has $1 \lt r \lt 2$.